# Ionic has-tabs overwritten has-tabs-top

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm working in a app with Ionic-tabs, and when i run on android device, the tabs are covering the content.

The usually fix is set has-tabs-top on the content div, but ionic has-tabs.pane are overwritten has-tabs-top css

```
.has-tabs.pane, .bar-footer.has-tabs.pane {
    bottom: 49px;
    height: auto;
}


.has-tabs-top {
    top: 93px;
}


<ion-content padding="true" class="has-tabs-top">
```

I'm looking a way to fix it without changing the css class

Comment: can you post a code pen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this in your config method of your app module

```
$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("bottom"); //Places them at the bottom for all OS
$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("standard"); //Makes them all look the same across all OS
```